# Is it possible to have users register without having a password?

Tags: password, user-registration

I'm developing a plugin and I wanted to allow users to just subscribe to a custom user level without having a password sent to them via email. this level will not be able to contribute to the site, so just reading capability.
I will use this subscription to add the email to a mailing list and to allow the user to buy on this website, nothing else.
Do you have any suggestions on how to build this up?

Comment: Use random generated passwords as it's not being used for later use

Comment: @danix This plugin will give you an idea - https://github.com/fatwp/AJAX-Quick-Subscribe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just wanting to add them to a mailing list, you really don't need to create a user account for them. Just use something like this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mail-list/ or Gravity Forms to capture their email addresses.

The fact that you then say "to allow the user to buy on this website" seems to suggest that the user *will* need to log in - how will you authenticate them otherwise?

Comment: this is a good point, I'll have to rethink about this plugin.. thanks a lot!

Comment: I think Mail-list is not available. Could you check?